# How to properly use a cookie

Tags: php

good day..I have a problem, but I think it's not really a problem. I'm just curios about the php cookie. I have set it up on my website. 
I use it as a basis for "remember me" checkbox and it's working properly,but, I don't really what are the importance of setting up a cookie. Will I use it to automatically logged in a user which does not press the logout button but maybe just close the browser? or can I use it just to save thier email address and let them fill-up the password field? It really bothers me. What is really the importance of cookie. What I mean is, how do I use the cookie properly? I hope you understand my question. Please help me clear this cookie thing. Really appreciate if you would answer this. Thanks. don't be harsh on me :-)

Comment: thanks for the edit admin. Please don't make this for granted. I think there are many of us having this kind of problem

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are a user-controllable variables. Just like $_GET. So, before using it, for example, as a path parameter in accessing files, take care that it's value is really what it should be.

Setting setcookie() optional parameters can prevent a lot of attacks too.
Documentation is here:
http://php.net/setcookie

When you call setcookie(), it sends a soft request to browser to set cookie amongst other responses, so it is up to browser to support cookies or not. Only save public and not important data in cookies. By saving password in cookies, a man-in-the-middle attack will reveals password. Also by accessing to client's hardware fore a few minutes, kids can reveal passwords too. So, what you need is storing a long really-random login key + row id of signin table in database, where it has columns such as row-id, random-login-key, user-id, signin-time, last-visit time, etc.

A 256 bit (32 bytes) or 512 bit (64 bytes) random value for login key is enough.

mt_rand() and rand() are not secure random generators, so use one of following functions to generate a secure random bytes:

http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

http://php.net/mcrypt_create_iv

```
# License: wtfpl - http://www.wtfpl.net/txt/copying/
function random_bytes($size)
{
    if(function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes'))
    {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($size, $is_strong);

        if($is_strong === true)
            return $bytes;
    }

    if(function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv'))
        return mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
    else
    {
        $bytes = '';
        for($i=0; $i < $size; $i++)
            $bytes .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
        return $bytes;
    }
}
```

Even though it's not totally secure to save login key to cookies, but it is the only way that all websites do it. For a total security, use HTTPS protocol.

Also, you may want to check out [Authentication](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet), [Session Management](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) and [cookie theft/session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Cookie_Theft/Session_Hijacking) cheat sheets at owasp.org.

Comment: will your website still run if the browser does not accept a cookie? can i store the usernames and passwords to a cookie? will that be secure?

Comment: No. That's totally insecure that's why we have `sessions`

Comment: I updated my answer, so use what I said, or what sessions as @Uchiha said.

Comment: so what you mean here is, i need to have a random encrypted cookie and put it to the database together with the user_id.  No offense but i don't need a code here. I just need a clarification or more elaboration about the cookie. Google doesn't talk more about cookie. I need someone who can explain it further. I don't want my website hacked by someone just because of that cookie. and btw, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes. On login page, send row id + random login key to user, then, in other pages check that if both cookies exists, and if $_COOKIE[row] AND  $_COOKIE[key] exists in db too, then consider it as the same user that you saved it's user-id in db. You can also check that last-visit-time is not for more than 1 month ago too for more security :)

Comment: Also, the $_COOKIE[key] is not encrypted, it is just a secure random value, which means it is more random than a simple rand() function.

Comment: I added 3 useful links in the answer.

Comment: yeah..I think i need to update the cookie everytime the user logs in. is that right? and just some encryption as you say.thanks a lot @David

Comment: You need to update both cookies and last-visit-time on every page visit. Cookies are deleted automatically after a period of time(setcookie()'s expire parameter) , and by re-setting it, you can extend that.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot bro. is visit time really necessary?

Comment: If you don't set a timeout, it is possible that an attacker enters into system even 10 years after signin.